# Child class access to private member variables in the parent class

Tags: php, oop, private-members

I try to create class `User` and `Teacher` extends from `User` class
I have a problem with the `Teacher` class can access to *private* member variables in the `parent` class it's weird.

`User` Class

```
<?php

class User
{
    private $username;

    protected $password;

    public function login()
    {
        return 'login';
    }

    public function register()
    {
        return 'register';
    }
}
```

`Teacher` Class

```
<?php
class Teacher extends User
{
    public $id;

    public $name;

    public $description;

    public $email;

    public $phone;


    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }


    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

> PHP 7.2.14 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2019 22:23:26) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>
> Windows 10

Any logical reason?

Comment: If you change the User class to: ```abstract class User {```. Does it work?

Comment: You are misinterpreting your results. On the child class you do not have access to private properties of the parent, but creating new ones.

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP versions or anything. See here https://3v4l.org/I2XW1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->username` does not call parent private member `username`, it creates new child object property `username` dynamically.

To keep `username` private in Teacher, you need to set field as protected. Protected fields means that is private for super class and also for children.

Answer (score -1):

You can not access private properties or methods of class from outside of it.

`Teacher::$username` is an undefined property in this case (1. private property of parent is invisible for it's childs 2. it is not defined in itself), so whenever you call `getUsername()` a notice is thrown and depending on your error reporting config you'll see this on screen or not.

If you want to acces `User::$username` from `Teacher` class, you have to make it protected or public- what's the difference: check this for more informations
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php